# Error message: "We're sorry, the link that you clicked on could not be served. We are experiencing a temporary delay due to high volume."

Tags: error

One of our retail websites sometimes displays a blank page that just says:

> We're sorry, the link that you clicked on could not be served. We are
>   experiencing a temporary delay due to high volume. Please click RELOAD
>   and try again. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Where does this error message come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That appears to be an error message from [SiteSpect](https://sitespect.force.com/onlinehelp/s/article/SiteSpect-Troubleshooting-FAQs#why_does_sitespect_display):

> Why does SiteSpect display this timeout message:  “We're sorry, the
>   link that you clicked on could not be served. We are experiencing a
>   temporary delay due to high volume. Please click RELOAD and try again.
>   We apologize for the inconvenience.”?
>
> SiteSpect is designed to
>   proactively close connections and display a message to alert users
>   whenever either of the following two conditions occur:
>
> - SiteSpect establishes an HTTP connection with your origin and the origin does
>     not respond with any data within a predefined period (the default is
>     60 seconds).
> - SiteSpect is not able to establish a TCP connection with
>     the origin.
>
> This is not a SiteSpect error state. The timeout message
>   is configurable. Contact the SiteSpect Help Desk at
>   helpdesk@sitespect.com to customize this timeout message.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the web server is overloaded and sitespec is timing out. This could be caused by too many concurrent connections to the webserver. The only way I see to get rid of it permenently is to lease a CDN server system and horizontally expand the website.